# How to get junit 4 test code coverage programaticly using jacoco or some other tool?

Tags: code-coverage, junit4, jacoco

I want to run my tests and then to create a report. I want to add code coverage in to my report.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

How are you running jacoco?  For example if you are running it through Maven, it [generates an XML report](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html).  Which you can use XPath to parse to programmatically grab the coverage numbers.